# How to convert Openh264 DecodeFrameNoDelay output format to OpenCV matrix?

Tags: c++, opencv, openh264

I want to convert output format of `DecodeFrameNoDelay` function is `yuvData` and `bufferInfo` to OpenCV matrix that I can use `imshow` function to display frame on window

Link git to DecodeFrameNoDelay detail: https://github.com/cisco/openh264/wiki/ISVCDecoder#decodeframenodelay

Below is my code use to decode frame with Openh264

```
ISVCDecoder *decoder;
SBufferInfo bufferInfo;
SDecodingParam decodingParam;
uint8_t** yuvData;

void init(int width, int height) {
    WelsCreateDecoder(&decoder);
    decodingParam = {0};
    decodingParam.sVideoProperty.eVideoBsType = VIDEO_BITSTREAM_AVC;
    decoder->Initialize(&decodingParam);
    bufferInfo = {0};
    bufferInfo.iBufferStatus = 1;

    yuvData = new uint8_t*[3];
    yuvData[0] = new uint8_t[width * height];
    yuvData[1] = new uint8_t[width * height / 4];
    yuvData[2] = new uint8_t[width * height / 4];

}

bool decode(const unsigned char* rawEncodedData, int rawEncodedDataLength, uint8_t** yuvData, char *name) {
    int err = decoder->DecodeFrameNoDelay(rawEncodedData, rawEncodedDataLength, yuvData, &bufferInfo);

    if (err != 0) {
        std::cout << "H264 decoding failed. Error code: " << err << "." << std::endl;
        parseErrorCode(err);
        return false;
    }

    printf("H264 decoding success, err: %d, name: %s, status: %d\n", err, name, bufferInfo.iBufferStatus);

    return true;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: You need to create `Mat` object either by constructor version which sets image sizes or with `create()` function, and then copy pixel information from `yuvData` buffers to Mat's `data` buffer plane by plane. Then may be convert it to some other encoding, e.g. RGB, since I'm not sure if OpenCV can do anything except conversion with YUV images...

Answer (score 0):

There is a `stride` parameter that you should consider when performing copy. Here is a code that decodes frame into opencv `cv::Mat`:

```
inline void copyWithStride(
        void* dst, const void* src,
        size_t width, size_t height, size_t stride
) {
    for (size_t row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
        uint8_t* posFrom = (uint8_t*)src + row * stride;
        uint8_t* posTo = (uint8_t*)dst + row * width;
        memcpy(posTo, posFrom, width);
    }
}

cv::Mat decode(const unsigned char* rawEncodedData, int rawEncodedDataLength) {
    SBufferInfo sDstBufInfo;
    memset(&sDstBufInfo, 0, sizeof(SBufferInfo));

    unsigned char *pData[3] = {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};

    int rv = decoder->DecodeFrameNoDelay(
        rawEncodedData,
        rawEncodedDataLength,
        pData,
        &sDstBufInfo
    );

    int stride0 = sDstBufInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iStride[0];
    int stride1 = sDstBufInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iStride[1];
    
    cv::Mat imageYuvCh[3];
    cv::Mat imageYuvMiniCh[3];

    copyWithStride(imageYuvCh[0].data, pData[0], width, height, stride0);
    copyWithStride(imageYuvMiniCh[1].data, pData[1], width/2, height/2, stride1);
    copyWithStride(imageYuvMiniCh[2].data, pData[2], width/2, height/2, stride1);
    
    cv::resize(imageYuvMiniCh[1], imageYuvCh[1], cv::Size(width, height));
    cv::resize(imageYuvMiniCh[2], imageYuvCh[2], cv::Size(width, height));
    
    cv::Mat resultYuv;
    cv::merge(imageYuvCh, 3, resultYuv);
    
    cv::Mat result;
    cvtColor(imgYUV, result, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR);
    return result;
}
```